# How to avoid any mutable things in this builder?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I have a simple Scala class like this:

```
class FiltersBuilder {

  def build(filter: CommandFilter) = {
    val result = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
    if (filter.activity.isDefined) {
      result += ("activity" -> """ some specific expression """)
    } // I well know that manipulating option like this is not recommanded, 
      //it's just for the simplicity of the  example
    if (filter.gender.isDefined) {
      result += ("gender" -> """ some specific expression """)
    }
    result.toMap //in order to return an immutable Map
  }
}
```

using this class so:

```
case class CommandFilter(activity: Option[String] = None, gender: Option[String] = None)
```

The `result` content depends on the nature of the selected filters and their associated and hardcoded expressions (`String`).

Is there a way to transform this code snippet by removing this "mutability" of the `mutable.Map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each filter field to a tuple while you add the result to a `Seq`, then filter out the `None`s with `flatten` finally convert the `Seq` of tuples to a `Map` with `toMap`.
For adding more fields to filter you just have to add a new line to the `Seq`

```
    def build(filter: CommandFilter) = {
      // map each filter filed to the proper tuple
      // as they are options, map will transform just the Some and let the None as None
      val result = Seq(
        filter.activity.map(value => "activity" -> s""" some specific expression using $value """),
        filter.gender.map(value => "gender" -> s""" some specific expression using $value """)
      ).flatten // flatten will filter out all the Nones
      result.toMap // transform list of tuple to a map
    }
```

Hope it helps.
Gaston.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are at most 2 elements in your `Map`:

```
val activity = filter.activity.map(_ => Map("activity" -> "xx"))
val gender = filter.gender.map(_ => Map("gender" -> "xx"))
val empty = Map[String, String]()
activity.getOrElse(empty) ++ gender.getOrElse(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to achieve it with this solution:

```
class FiltersBuilder(commandFilter: CommandFilter) {

   def build = {
     val result = Map[String, String]()
     buildGenderFilter(buildActivityFilter(result))
   }

   private def buildActivityFilter(expressions: Map[String, String]) =
     commandFilter.activity.fold(expressions)(activity => result + ("activity" -> """ expression regarding activity """))

   private def buildGenderFilter(expressions: Map[String, String]) =
     commandFilter.gender.fold(expressions)(gender => result + ("gender" -> """ expression regarding gender """))

}
```

Any better way?